# Non-connectedness in the plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let us have open $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $x\in V$. Now, how can I prove that the quotient space $V\backslash\{x\}$ is not simply connected? Pictorially I understand it as the failure of a loop to be the constant loop $C_{x}$ at $x$. One hint I am given is to consider a small circle around that point and see what happens with the inclusion $C \hookrightarrow V\backslash\{x\} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{x\}$. Now I am confused.

Comment: I assume you want $V$ open?

Comment: Yes, sorry to not mention it.

Answer (score 2):

So, from your inclusion $V \setminus \{x\} \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{x\}$, we have a homomorphism of fundamental groups $\pi_1(V\setminus\{x\}) \to \pi_1(\Bbb R^2\setminus\{x\})$. If $V \setminus\{x\}$ was simply connected, then the image of this must be trivial; but if we pick a small enough loop rotating once counterclockwise around $x$ (small enough that it's contained in $V$), the composite map $S^1 \to V\setminus\{x\} \to \Bbb R^2 \setminus\{x\}$ is not null-homotopic (it represents a generator in $\pi_1(\Bbb R^2\setminus\{x\})$). This map is in the image of the above homomorphism, so $V \setminus\{x\}$ can't be simply connected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you be kind enough to make it a bit more clear or wordy after the end of the brackets? ".. the composite map..." This $S^1$ is representing the loop right? And the last part: this map is the image of the above homomorphism, so $V\backslash \{x\}$ cannot be simply connected. Is this some theorem?

Comment: Yes, $S^1$ here represents the loop. This map represents a nontrivial element of $\pi_1(\Bbb R^2\setminus\{x\})$ - agreed?

Comment: Yes, I see that.

Comment: So this nontrivial element is in the *image* of the homomorphism $\pi_1(V\setminus \{x\}) \to \pi_1(\Bbb R^2\setminus\{x\}$ (just from writing down what the homomorphism actually is). But if $V \setminus \{x\}$ was simply connected, $\pi_1(V \setminus \{x\}) = 0$, so its image would be trivial!

Comment: Hm, ok, I think I see this. Thanks a lot. On an unrelated topic, since you seem to handle very well the subject, do you know any reference where all the results of alg. topology are collected? I.e. a "resume" that one needs to know (I struggle with all those pages I have to go back and forth in my book) Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Marion Unfortunately I don't know a source like that off the top of my head. You might make one yourself - Hatcher's algebraic topology book has lots of important results; you might write down the statements of all of his theorems (in, say, Ch. 1) in a separate document.